# How to roll n dice

Tags: python, numpy

I have been looking on stack and spend several hours browsing to try and solve this. Task is:

Use a For loop to perform dice experiments with increasing number of dice rolls.
Perform these experiments up to a number of =1000

I am struggling  to add the number of rolls into the for loop function. What I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000
roll = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
result = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    roll[i] = np.random.randint(1, 7,)
for i in range(1, N):
    result[i] = np.mean(roll[0:i])

results=np.array(result)
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000
results = np.zeros(N)

for i in range(1, N+1):
  roll = np.random.randint(1, 7, size = i)
  results[i-1] = np.mean(roll)
```

at each iteration the mean value of all the dice rolls is stored in results